# How can I split the power from a single PSU between multiple motherboards (with a twist)?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I am looking to build a home blade unit to save on space (need them locally) and cost, as I need 20 - 40 servers. I've done the basic work on design, but here lies my biggest problem(s). I have no idea how to power these! Each blade chassis will need 2 x 1200w - 1600w PSU's.

24 pin ATX power connector
4 pin 12V power connector
SATA power connector

My questions are as follows:
How can I split the power from each PSU to say 16 - 20 blades?
Would there be any way to be able to remotely control the power given to each blade (just to motherboard/24 pin ATX power connector)?

It's a bit easier with the SATA power connectors. Each PSU has a few SATA power ports and I have found a few [multipliers](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10226&cs_id=1022604&p_id=8794&seq=1&format=2) for the SATA drives (each unit gets one drive.). However, I'd prefer it if I could find a power/data cable [like so](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10226&cs_id=1022605&p_id=7639&seq=1&format=2), which should make cabling much easier in the tight space.

This leaves the ATX and 12v power connectors. I can't find any solutions for these. Would I have to build my own or custom order them? If so, where can I order them from? Will these be a problem?

Also, I need remote power control. Unfortunately, the motherboards don't support Intel AMT, so this leaves me with two options: upgrade to a motherboard that does or figure out a way to do the power management at another level. The cost of upgrading the motherboards would end up being several thousand dollars, so I think it might be worth pursuing a different method.

If anyone has any ideas, solutions, information, or guidance: this would be much appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: 40 blades, each with two 1600w supplies? That's 128kW.  How about a nuclear pile?

Comment: @Majenko My estimate is ~60w per blade, however, I'd like to leave room in-case I'm wrong. Of course it's better to spend a few dollars more and not have to worry about it then monitor power usage and fret if it turns out each one uses more. These are all relatively low power CPU's, so I expect typical usage to be between 50 - 65 watts, depending on how heavily each CPU is being utilized.

Comment: @Passerby My bad! I meant blade chassis not each blade itself. Haha, that would be insanity. I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Don't your servers have integrated psus with C13 connectors? A simple remote controlled power strip (called PDU for racks) is ~US$1000. If not, having that PDU with a simple ATX PSU per blade would do the trick, and reduce the impact of a single point failure.

Comment: @MisterMystère I am custom building this blade unit from scratch.

Comment: Then integrate a PSU per blade or put it externally, then control the mains socket on the PDU remotely (some PDUs are IP, see APC for example). I personally wouldn't rely on a single power supply for 20 servers unless it is redundant so the cost saving would definitely need to be great not to go for 1 blade 1 PSU.

Comment: Don't you have wake up on LAN features (is that what AMT is?)?

Comment: @MisterMystère The entire point of a blade system is reduction in PSU's leading to gains in available space.

Comment: @MisterMystère I need to be able to remotely kill the power, not via the OS.

Comment: In that case a bunch of relays should do, some boards are available off the shelf for USB control but maybe you want Ethernet ones ("network attached relays").